# scala - parse json of more than 22 elements into case class

Tags: json, scala

This question or similar ones were posted before, however none of the solutions work any more with latest libraries. After extensive searching as of now I found no evidence that latest versions of most popular libraries `spray-json` or `play-json` (or their plugins) can handle this case. Is there something that can parse a json of more than 22 elements into scala case class? Since scala 2.11 case classes are no longer limited to 22 elements. Please, only fully working solutions. Obvious json example below.

```
{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3,
    "d": 4,
    "e": 5,
    "f": 6,
    "g": 7,
    "h": 8,
    "i": 9,
    "j": 10,
    "k": 11,
    "l": 12,
    "m": 13,
    "n": 14,
    "o": 15,
    "p": 16,
    "q": 17,
    "r": 18,
    "s": 19,
    "t": 20,
    "u": 21,
    "v": 22,
    "w": 23
}
```

**UPDATE:** This is a case when you have no control over json structure, for instance it's retrieved from a 3rd party api. An example of twitter's tweet json: http://pastebin.com/h8fHAsd8

Comment: Is it practical to have such monolithic case classes? What are the use cases?

Comment: @DominykasMostauskis see my update, please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) does, with automatic codec derivation supported by [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). Note that unlike json4s's case class decoding, there's no runtime reflection happening here:

```
case class Foo(
  a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int, e: Int, f: Int, g: Int, h: Int, i: Int,
  j: Int, k: Int, l: Int, m: Int, n: Int, o: Int, p: Int, q: Int, r: Int,
  s: Int, t: Int, u: Int, v: Int, w: Int
)

import io.circe.generic.auto._, io.circe.jawn.decode

val json = """{
  "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6, "g": 7, "h": 8, "i": 9,
  "j": 10, "k": 11, "l": 12, "m": 13, "n": 14, "o": 15, "p": 16, "q": 17,
  "r": 18, "s": 19, "t": 20, "u": 21, "v": 22, "w": 23
}"""

val result: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error, Foo] = decode[Foo](json)
```

Here's a minimal `build.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0-M5" cross CrossVersion.full
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.1.1",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.1.1",
  "io.circe" %% "circe-jawn" % "0.1.1"
)
```

The upcoming 0.2.0 release (currently available as a snapshot) includes a lot of improvements to generic derivation, but for a simple example like this the 0.1.1 behavior is the same.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly interesting. I have a bonus question though - would it be able to deal with nested json?

Comment: @Caballero Yes, for sure! There are some corner cases where the automatic derivation breaks down for nested case classes in 0.1.1, but they're mostly fixed in 0.2.0.

Comment: Yep, compiler seems to choke on the massive json I'm trying to parse with an error `diverging implicit expansion for type io.circe.Decoder[Foo] starting with method decodeCaseClass in trait GenericInstances`. Any idea when version 0.2.0 is coming out?

Comment: @Caballero I'm just waiting for Shapeless 2.3.0—I'd expect something like next couple of weeks. There are 0.2.0 snapshots on Sonatype now, and I'd be curious to hear if you're running into the same error on them.

Comment: Snapshot compiles, but still fails to parse the json. Example is here: http://pastebin.com/w8UQ8ip3 Just to note - json4s parses it just fine. Hopefully it's nothing major and in the future I can use circe still.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Caballero—it is [a bug](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/issues/73), and I'm working on it.

Comment: @Caballero Just FYI, I don't have this fixed yet, but [we're close](https://gitter.im/milessabin/export-hook?at=562d429248fc9e2d6fe8ddb6), and it'll definitely be resolved before the 0.2.0 release.

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Comment: @Caballero Okay, we've got a fix in place, and it'll be available in a new snapshot as soon as export-hook 1.0.2 lands: https://github.com/travisbrown/circe/pull/77

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.

Comment: @Caballero Thanks! The snapshot should be updated today, when export-hook 1.0.2 is released.

Comment: So I tried to use the new version with the same example (on pastebin) and now it gives me this: `Left(io.circe.DecodingFailure: Attempt to decode value on failed cursor: El(DownField(entities),false),El(DownField(user),true),El(DownField(retweeted_status),true))`

Comment: @Caballero Sorry for the long delay in responding, but the failure is legitimate—`Entities` is required in your `Users` case class, but in your example JSON it's missing in at least one case. Making the `Entities` member optional in `Users` fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For play-json, the play-json-extensions offer an extension that supports >22 fields and a few other use cases like serializing sealed trait structures, singleton objects, etc.

```
import org.cvogt.play.json.Jsonx
implicit val jsonFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Foo] // Instead of Json.format
```

https://github.com/cvogt/play-json-extensions

circe/argonaut is certainly worth checking out as well. Not sure about how they compare in terms of features and stability compared to play-json/play-json-extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, but there just isn't a clear example of how to parse a json with >22 elements into a case class and play-json implicit conversion doesn't work because of the same 22 element limit issue.

Comment: Just use Jsonx.formatCaseClass for your 22+ case class where you would have normally used Json.format. Everything else should stay the same. Still doesn't work?

Comment: This is an example I'm trying this: http://pastebin.com/HLJK4wWC I might be doing something wrong, but I just can't find a clear working example close to this case.

Comment: You are missing the jsonFormat for Bar. You need it just as in play-json. Then things should just work. Added a ticket, trying to improve the error message. https://github.com/cvogt/play-json-extensions/issues/19

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but still getting the same error plus another one: `reference to Json is ambiguous; it is imported twice in the same scope by 
import _root_.play.api.libs.json._ and 
import play.libs.Json 
 implicit val barFormat = Jsonx.formatCaseClass[Bar]`

Comment: I saw you import play.libs.Json, instead import play.api.libs.Json. If it is still not working it is probably something else silly, if you push the sbt project to github, I can try to fix it

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @cvogt and other my personal requirements I've develop a library to manage transparently via macro the > 22 fields and other features.

The library is [here](https://github.com/aparo/play-json-extra) and [documentation](http://play-json-extra.megl.io/)

The JsonFormat annotation creates via macro a "pimped" json format that manage a lot of stuff.

Main Features are:

- Play JSON for ScalaJS
- JsonFormat macro annotation for lazy people
- Default field values populated in missing JSON
- Field rewrite for Play JSON ("key")
- +22 field case class formatter and more Play Json Extension
- Joda Datetime for Scala and ScalaJS
- Strong Typed Enum (String and Int) for Scala and ScalaJS
- Variant Types

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s):

```
scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

scala> case class Foo(
     |                 a: String,
     |                 b: String,
     |                 c: String,
     |                 d: String,
     |                 e: String,
     |                 f: String,
     |                 g: String,
     |                 h: String,
     |                 i: String,
     |                 j: String,
     |                 k: String,
     |                 l: String,
     |                 m: String,
     |                 n: String,
     |                 o: String,
     |                 p: String,
     |                 q: String,
     |                 r: String,
     |                 s: String,
     |                 t: String,
     |                 u: String,
     |                 v: String,
     |                 w: String
     |                 )
defined class Foo

scala> 

scala>     implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@6eb0a5cb

scala>     val f = parse("{\n    \"a\": 1,\n    \"b\": 2,\n    \"c\": 3,\n    \"d\": 4,\n    \"e\": 5,\n    \"f\": 6,\n    \"g\": 7,\n    \"h\": 8,\n    \"i\": 9,\n    \"j\": 10,\n    \"k\": 11,\n    \"l\": 12,\n    \"m\": 13,\n    \"n\": 14,\n    \"o\": 15,\n    \"p\": 16,\n    \"q\": 17,\n    \"r\": 18,\n    \"s\": 19,\n    \"t\": 20,\n    \"u\": 21,\n    \"v\": 22,\n    \"w\": 23\n}")
           .extract[Foo]
f: Foo = Foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23)
```