# Convert scala case class to json

Tags: json, scala, spray

I need to convert scala case class to json. I am using spray json.
The problem is my case class having more then 22 fields, and spray json supports to 22 fields only.

I cant write like

```
implicit val someformat = jsonformat25(Somecaseclass)

case class Color(name: String, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int)

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat4(Color)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._
import spray.json._

val json = Color("CadetBlue", 95, 158, 160).toJson
val color = json.convertTo[Color]
```

I saw there is and tried with it, but it's not working. Please suggest some solution.

```
implicit object format extends RootJsonFormat[SomeObject] {
    def write(a: SomeObject) = a match {
      case p: SomeObject=> p.toJson
    }
    def read(value: JsValue) = {
      value.convertTo[SomeObject]
    }
  }
```

Please dont suggest to split class params and make nested case class.. my requirements are I have more than 22 fields in one case class.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571677/22-fields-limit-in-scala-2-11-play-framework-2-3-case-classes-and-functions). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318802/scala-parse-json-of-more-than-22-elements-into-case-class). And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426668/json-reads-for-case-class-with-more-than-22-fields?rq=1).

Comment: never used spray-json, but if you are willing to use Play-Json check http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/  and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/

Answer (score -1):

You could use - https://github.com/sitetester/json-handler

- It's easy to use and supports converting nested case class(s) into JSON with proper indentation.

Comment: The lib you gave does not produce valid JSON somehow, there are equal signs, no commas, etc