# case class more than 22 fields to CSV in Scala

Tags: scala, csv, case-class

Is there any library which converts case class with more than 22 fields to CSV?
I tried using [kantan](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv) but the encoder allows only 22 fields.

P.S: I serialised a json string to 27 fields case class using circe with a simple decode function. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33319168/7295660).

Comment: If you found answer by yourself you can also add answer directly under your question and mark it as right, it will help to other people found similar answer faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow managed to find a solution to write all the fields to a file.

1. I split the 27 field case class into two case classes.
2. Then I wrote a CellEncode implicit for those two case classes
3. Then RowEncoder implicit for the case class which contains the 2 newly created case classes as fields
4. Final Excel will have 2 columns with all 27 column information pipe separated. Then you can convert the pipe separated content to columns in Excel.

```
case class subCaseClass1 ( id: Int, name: String) //customer info
case class subCaseClass2 (paymentId: Int, itemId: Int) //payment info
case class finalCaseClass (header: subCaseClass1, payment: subCaseClass2)

//Cell encode Implicits
implicit val CustomerInfoCellEncode: CellEncoder[subCaseClass1] = CellEncoder.from(x => s"${x.asInstanceOf[subCaseClass1].id}|${x.asInstanceOf[subCaseClass1].name}")
implicit val PaymentInfoCellEncode: CellEncoder[subCaseClass2] = CellEncoder.from(x => s"${x.asInstanceOf[subCaseClass2].paymentId}|${x.asInstanceOf[subCaseClass2].itemId}")

// RowEncoder implicit
implicit val paymentTupleRowEncoder: RowEncoder[finalCaseClass]= RowEncoder.encoder(0, 1)((is: finalCaseClass) => (is.subCaseClass1, is.subCaseClass2))

//Write to CSV
new File("test.csv").writeCsv(value,rfc) //value is List(finalCaseClass)
```

Comment: As suggested by the developer of the library, "But you could also handwrite an encoder - it’s essentially a function from your case class to a list of strings", I did the same thing now.

You can skip the splitting into case classes. You can directly do a row encoding without providing the number of fields the case class has.


```
RowEncoder.encoder((x: PaymentDataFlatFileStructure) => s"${x.asInstanceOf[PaymentDataFlatFileStructure].id}") //make your 27 field string
```

Answer (score 0):

There are might be several solutions for this. Obviously if you could convert a json to 27 fields case class, then you can first convert the csv to a json and then decode the json.
You can find converter libs:
1. [here](https://github.com/scalajs-io/csvtojson)
2. [here](https://blog.datumbrain.com/2018/09/25/csv-to-json-using-jackson-scala.html)

Secondly, there is already closed issue on github repo. They suggest to split large case class into smaller case classes.

```scala
import kantan.csv._

final case class RootModel(model1: Model1, model2: Model2)
final case class Model1(value: Int)
final case class Model2(value: String)

object RootModel {
  implicit val headerDecoder: HeaderDecoder[RootModel] = {

    // Decoders for Model1 and Model2
    implicit val model1Decoder: HeaderDecoder[Model1] = HeaderDecoder.decoder("Header1")(Model1)
    implicit val model2Decoder: HeaderDecoder[Model2] = HeaderDecoder.decoder("Header2")(Model2)

    new HeaderDecoder[RootModel] {

      override def fromHeader(header: Seq[String]) =
        // Turns the header into row decoders for Model1 and Model2
        for {
          model1D ← model1Decoder.fromHeader(header)
          model2D ← model2Decoder.fromHeader(header)
        } yield
            // Merge these two decoders into a single RowDecoder
          RowDecoder.from { row ⇒
            for {
              model1 ← model1D.decode(row)
              model2 ← model2D.decode(row)
            } yield RootModel(model1, model2)
          }

      // There's unfortunately nothing we can do if no header is provided.
      override def noHeader = sys.error("Attempting to decode without a header.")
    }
  }

}
```

How to use it:

```scala
scala> import kantan.csv._
scala> import kantan.csv.ops._
scala> "Header1,Header2\n1,foo".asCsvReader[RootModel](rfc.withHeader).foreach(println _)
// Success(RootModel(Model1(1),Model2(foo)))
```

[Source](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv/issues/104)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Though the idea provided does not match to what I was looking for (I am looking for exactly the opposite Encoder case and not the Decoder part), I can try to build an encoder taking your comment a an example